# ComboBox ItemsSource binding doesn't update with Observable Collection Add

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple wpf app, that I want to try to use ItemsSource binding from xaml. When I click the button. it should be updated also in the UI, but it doesn't.

Why doesn't it work?

Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="SendRawEthernetPacketsGUI.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding test}"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SendRawEthernetPacketsGUI
{

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> test = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        test.Add("fdfddf");
    }
}
}
```

It feels kinda stupid to even ask this, but even looking in google didn't help me. So can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding never worked in the first place. You can only bind to *properties* not *fields*.

Try this instead:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> test { get; set; }

public Window1()
{
    Test = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}
```

Or if you want some tricky C# 6 magic:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> test => new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

This is a *function bodied-member* and compiles to a read-only property that is initialized to the new `ObservableCollection`

Caveats/Design Errors:

Note that in both cases you aren't using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so wholesale assignments to the collection won't be picked up by the UI. You should also be using PascalCase for your public properties, and using a proper view model instead of binding to the code-behind.

Comment: It worked! thanks. 2 questions: why can you bind only to properties? what is the problem with fields? if you try to bind in code behind - you can bind to fields. 2) what does `=>` in C#6? delegate?

Comment: @789 Its just the rule, and has to do with how the binding system uses reflection to find the binding targets. As for 2, => reads "such that" and *usually* is used with lambda expressions. In this case it defines a function bodied member. I added a bit of explanation to my answer.

Comment: `system uses reflection` explain?

Comment: @789 Without trying to explain all of reflection (which is a decent sized topic in C#) the system dynamically looks for members with the name you provided on the `Path` variable of your binding. When it does so, it only looks for properties (not fields or methods). Its just how they chose to implement it. Here's an article on reflection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx Do note that this is an *advanced* concept that is **very easily misused**. I would steer clear of it until you have a good handle on programming in .NET.

Comment: basically reflection is creating custom objects at run time right?

Comment: @789 It can be used to create objects based on a `Type` object (`Activator.CreateInstance`) yes, but is used for **SO** much more than that. Come by the WPF room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf if you want to chat about it.